# selenium rollup element not found

Tags: selenium, rollup

I am new to selenium ui-element,before this I always choose selenium IDE.When I tried use the rollup command,I define a rollup manager in a uimap.js file:

```
myRollupManager.addRollupRule({
    name: 'login_in'
    , description: 'login'
    , pre: 'xxx'
    , post: 'xxx'
    , commandMatchers: []
    , expandedCommands: [
    {
        command: 'click'
        , target: 'loginbutton'
    }
    ]
});
```

The loginbutton element is like this:

```
myMap.addElement('LoginPages', {
    name: 'loginbutton'
    , description: 'login button'
    , locator: "//*[@id='login-form']/*/button"  
});
```

but when i executed the following command in IDE:

```
|command|target|value|
|click|login_in||
```

i always got the "element loginbutton not found" ERROR:

I've tried many kinds of xpath locator,each of them works fine when it comes to ide without rollup:

```
|command|target|value|
|click|//*[@id='login-form']/*/button||
|click|//xpath=//*/button||
```

I also tried input element with an id attribute when locator is " locator: "xpath=//*[@id='xxx']" ",that works very well,I really cannot figure out what is going on. Does anybody come across this similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
target:'loginbutton'
```

will not work.that's a locator,not an ui-element.Change it to:

```
{
    command: 'click'
    , target: 'ui=LoginPages::loginbutton()'
    //'login_button' will not work.that's a locator,not an ui-element
}
```